# Do I have to restart apache server every time I change a Craft PHP file?

Tags: craft3

When I make a change to a .php file of Craft, say `config/routes.php`, do I have to restart the server to take effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but make sure devMode is turned on in your development environment.